# Retrieving user data from LinkedIn API after they use LinkedIn Oauth Supabase

Tags: linkedin-api, supabase

So I am building an app where my users can create an account by signing in using the Supabase OAuth with LinkedIn as a provider.

I wanted to know if there is a way to then retrieve the information of that user (experiences & education) from LinkedIn directly. I heard something about a access token but can't find anything that is useful in the responses that I get from Supabase so I was wondering if anyone has an idea!

Many thanks!